# jQuery ajax passing null to controller in ASP .NET MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to send stringified array from view with $.ajax but I am constantly getting null in controller.
This is controller function:

```
[HttpPost]
        public void SaveColumnsToDb(string data)
        {
            var a = data;

        }
```

Console outputs:

```
str:  (2) ['SerialNumber', 'MeasurementUnit']
JSON str:  ["SerialNumber","MeasurementUnit"]
```

Whole function:

```
$("#popup-saveBtn").click(function () {
            var columns = [];
            var parentElement = document.getElementById("tableColumns");
            var childElements = parentElement.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]");

            // If checkbox is checked, push value to array
            for (i = 0; i < childElements.length; i++) {
                if (childElements[i].checked) {
                    columns.push(childElements[i].value);
                }
            }
            /*var strColumns = columns.join(";");*/

            console.log("str: ", columns);
            console.log("JSON str: ", JSON.stringify(columns));

            // Send data to AjaxSelectController
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("SaveColumnsToDb", "AjaxSelect", new { area = string.Empty })',
                type: 'POST',
                data: JSON.stringify(columns),
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
            });
        });
```

Comment: Either use `public void SaveColumnsToDb([FromBody]YourClass data)` or `public void SaveColumnsToDb(YourClass data)` note that `YourClass` means definate of `columns` in `C#` class

Comment: Columns are just string names for columns in tables, that's what I want to save in dbo.Profiles.
Do I really need to extend my Model ?

Comment: Try data:  JSON.stringify({ data: columns })

Comment: I think you should

Comment: Could I somehow send just string to controller? I would make CSV string from array and send that to controller.

Comment: Could you please share the structure of your string you want to pass?

Comment: You can only post `string` kind of data like this way for example `var column = "some data as string"` would be posted and you can get it in controller but for complex object you must have to use `[FromBody] string data`

Comment: Another way you could try `public void SaveColumnsToDb( [FromBody] object data)` but without `FromBody` you couldn't post complex object.

Answer (score 0):

as a matter of fact, since you are using contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',  you are trying to send a json inside of the request body, so use this syntax

```
[HttpPost]
public void SaveColumnsToDb([FromBody] string[] data)
```

Answer (score -1):

---

### Changed the parameter name.
When we use an ajax request then we have to pass value in data and In the URL part, we have to give only the action name and controller name.

```
[HttpPost]
public void SaveColumnsToDb(string dataResponse)
{
        var a = dataResponse;
}


$("#popup-saveBtn").click(function () {
    var columns = [];
    var parentElement = document.getElementById("tableColumns");
    var childElements = parentElement.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]");

    // If checkbox is checked, push value to array
    for (i = 0; i < childElements.length; i++) {
        if (childElements[i].checked) {
            columns.push(childElements[i].value);
        }
    }
    /*var strColumns = columns.join(";");*/

    console.log("str: ", columns);
    console.log("JSON str: ", JSON.stringify(columns));

    // Send data to AjaxSelectController
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("SaveColumnsToDb", "AjaxSelect")',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { dataResponse: JSON.stringify(columns)},
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    });
});
```

Comment: It still posting null data. You cannot sent this way. And it's not the correct answer.

Comment: And just my advice : never use a header font size for your answers.

Answer (score -1):

I managed to make it work.

Changed data property in $.ajax().

```
data: JSON.stringify({ data: strColumns })
```

I am sending only csv string, e.g. "abc;abc;abc"
Controller is same.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).